# Flutter - Text from assets file only shows when I resave dart file while the view is open

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I have the following widget where I want to load text from a file in the assets folder when the widget loads. Problem is that when I click on the link that opens up this widget, nothing shows at first but if I go in the file in visual studio code and resave the widget file, the text starts to show in the view.
Any ideas why is this happening?

Thank you!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

class Terms extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return TermsState();
  }
}

class TermsState extends State<Terms> {
  
  String termsText = '';
  fetchTermsText () async {
    String responseText;
    responseText =  await rootBundle.loadString('assets/terms.txt');
    setState(() async{
      termsText = responseText;
    });
  
  }

  void initState() {
    fetchTermsText();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Terms'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue[600],
        ),
        body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              text: termsText,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your fetchTermsText function is async its mean when you want to use it you have to use await, otherwise system not waiting for the response and you don't see anything when your widget show on first run.

Comment: ok I understand, if I do this I get an error. so what is the solution?
void initState() async{
    await fetchTermsText();
    super.initState();
  }

Comment: Time(Duration(milliseconds: 10), ()async{await fetchTermsText();});

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Future and FutureBuilder classes after some research online and now it works perfectly. Below is my full code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

class Terms extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return TermsState();
  }
}

class TermsState extends State<Terms> {

  Future<String> fetchTermsText () async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/terms.txt');;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Terms'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue[600],
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchTermsText(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
            return Container(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                    text: snapshot.data,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0)
            );
          }
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```